# Throw away extra variables for string formatting ("silent" string?)

Tags: python, string

For tuples we can use the star unpacking to throw everything we don't need into a `_` or similar, e.g. like so

```
some_tuple = ("obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4")
obj1, *_ = some_tuple
print(obj1)
```

So now I don't need to worry about the number of elements. I only want the N first.

If I made a string out of these, I could similarly do

```
some_text = "{} + {} + {} + {}".format(*some_tuple)
```

But now I realize that if I only wanted to write some expression

```
some_text = "{} + {}".format(*some_tuple)
```

I would have to go in and manually sort out the tuple to match the number of brackets. In this toy example this is of course not a problem, but if you want to output the results of some calculations with many variables on top of a graph, it quickly gets very cumbersome to unpack a tuple of lots of numbers.

What I'm looking for is, I don't know... a "silent" bracket for string formatting? E.g.

```
some_text = "{} {*silent*} {*silent*} + {}".format(*some_tuple_with_4_elements)
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this be okay with you:

```
some_tuple = ("obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4")
indices = (0,3)
some_text = "{} + {}".format(*(x for i, x in enumerate(some_tuple) if i in indices))
```

Comment: I just realized that `some_text = "{0} + {3}".format(*some_tuple_with_4_elements)` is one way to go, but your method is a very nice way to avoid numbering 10 brackets in a sea of text!

Comment: Yeah, I prefer keeping numbers in one place in case of editing :)

Comment: This approach is far from optimal, either my way or `"{} + {}".format(*(some_tuple[i] for i in indices))` @komodovaran_

Comment: @Chris_Rands All three approaches yield same `%timeit` results - `10000000 loops, best of 3: 22.1 ns per loop`

Comment: @Chris_Rands far from optimal in which way? They look strikingly similar to me, and timing isn't an issue.

Comment: @komodovaran well for such small datasets, optimisation may not be important, but zipa's approach iterates over the entirety of `some_tuple` with `enumerate` and then performs an in check on `indices`, which isn't even a `set()`. That's a lot of overhead. By contrast the other approaches just iterate over `indices` and extract the values by indexing

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing the inputs from [zipa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425861/6260170), you could use `operator.itemgetter()`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> some_tuple = ("obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4")
>>> indices = (0,3)
>>> "{} + {}".format(*itemgetter(*indices)(some_tuple))
'obj1 + obj4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers/comments:

```
some_text = "{} + {}".format(some_tuple[0], some_tuple[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question. This is solution.

```
for t in some_tuple:
    print("{} ".format(t))
```

This will display all the objects in tuple.